# How to get excel sheet column/row value?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a excel sheet

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="test.xlsx" sheet=1 rows="2-7" format="html" name="csvData">
```

How would i get the value of specic column and output the value?

For example:

```
                     Actual 
testtet test         9040416.9299998 
test test tettest    6406129.51
```

I would like to get column 2, row 3 which is the value of 6406129.51.

Comment: What have you actually tried?  If you have not tried anything, start by taking a look at the [Documentation on SpreadSheet functions](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-by-category/spreadsheet-functions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can get the value of specific rows and column form excel.

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="test.xlsx" rows="2-7" sheet="1" query="test"/>
<cfdump var="#test["col_2"][3]#">
```